# Pyramid: add_static_view with name='directory/subdirectory'

Tags: python, pyramid

I've just started learning Python recently and am using Pyramid as my web framework.

I'm trying to add a static view at `localhost/images/misc`:

```
config.add_static_view('images', 'C:/Project/Images/')
config.add_static_view('images/misc', 'C:/Path/To/Other/Images/')
```

But I get an error: `File does not exist: C:/Project/images/misc`

So it seems that the second line adding `images/misc` as a static view doesn't have any effect.

I've been searching for a while for a way to do this, but I haven't found anything. Is it possible to add a static view where the name contains a subdirectory? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood, pyramid turns the `name` part of the `add_static_view()` method into a Pyramid route predicate of the form `name/*subpath` (where `name` can contain slashes itself). A dedicated static asset view is attached to that route predicate.

In your configuration that means there would be both `images/*subpath` and `images/misc/*subpath` route predicates, *in that order*. When you then request a URL with the path `images/misc/foo.png` Pyramid finds the `images/*subpath` predicate *first*, and tries to look up the `misc` path element in the `'C:/Project/Images/'` folder, which fails.

Lucky for you, you can reverse the order of the registrations, simply register the `images/misc` path first:

```
config.add_static_view('images/misc', 'C:/Path/To/Other/Images/')
config.add_static_view('images', 'C:/Project/Images/')
```

Now the `images/misc/*subpath` predicate is registered first, and will match any `images/misc/` URLs before the other predicate is tested.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I guess I should have figured that out based on the part of Pyramid's URL Dispatch documentation about [route ordering](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#route-declaration-ordering) - I just didn't think about that applying to add_static_view as well. It's working now.

Comment: One other note - while this wasn't a part of my question, maybe it will help someone else trying to figure this out: If you have a Virtual Host set up in httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf, etc, and inside that virtual host you have `Alias /images C:/Project/Images`, then the `add_static_view` lines will have no effect. Martijn's answer didn't work at first and then I remembered I had also set up a virtual host like that. Once I took out the Alias line and swapped the two `add_static_view` lines, everything worked.